# 1989 Chev. Cavalier Firing Order

Tags: firing-order

[image] If  firing order 1423 equals firing order 1243,what cylinders do you connect the spark plug wire to from the coils? Will either work?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure where you get the idea the firing order 1423 equates to 1243? I'm *pretty* sure the actual firing order for the car is 1342. Do you have a distributor or a coil bank? My sources are saying a coil bank (two coils w/ two connectors each)? Is that right?

Comment: Source: Here from the question " Why is there no 1-4-2-3 Firing order?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the premise of the question and answer. I'm hoping a reread of them will help you understand. While you may be confused by that, I'd still like to help you with your issue. Please edit your question and put the information requested and I can not only give you the correct firing order, but can give you a descriptive image of what it should look like.

Comment: Source: Here from the question " Why is there no 1-4-2-3 Firing order? Manufactures book on this  illustrates 1-4-2-3  coming off the coil assembly module  and everywhere else , (internet) it says 1-2-4-3 and now you say 1-3-4-2. Picture this : facing the coil bank with power connector on the L  moving R to 6 pin module connector ,moving R to the 3 pin crank sensor connector. Behind all of this are 4 terminals for the spark plug leads. Listed in front of terminal  2 is a number  2 with 3 under it. Moving  R to terminal  3 is the number 1 over 4.Which terminals are  for   cylinders1,2,3,4?

Comment: @MarsBandit - Please put your additional information in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to your question, no, it won't work either way. In fact, it doesn't work either way. The thing is, the manufacturer has set the firing order for the 2.0L Cavalier 4-cyl engine (assuming that's what you have) as 1-3-4-2. Here is what it should look like under the hood:

[image]

( [Image from AutoZone.com Repair Guide](https://www.autozone.com/repairguides/GM-Cavalier-Sunbird-Skyhawk-Firenza-1982-1994/FIRING-ORDERS/FIRING-ORDERS/_/P-0900c1528003b8e4) )

The reason you can't just place them in any order is because the crankshaft and camshaft are both set to a specific order, then the ignition, knowing what the order should be, fires in that order. To change the firing order of any engine, at least the cam and the ignition system must be changed or modified to work correctly.

In the question [*Why is there no 1-4-2-3 Firing order?*](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/41758/4152), I answered as to why the firing order could only be one of two ways on an inline four cylinder engine. The basic things is, the crank can only be set one way and still work. While either of the firing orders of 1-3-4-2 or 1-2-4-3 could work on the standard crankshaft, it gives no reference to the other parts which would have to be changed in order to make it happen.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @MarsBandit - My suggestion to you is this: Put the spark plug wires onto the coils as your picture shows. If it doesn't run straight off, just swap the connections to the coils. You'll notice if you rearranged the two coils (swap them), the firing order is exactly what I'm showing above. You will not hurt the engine if it doesn't fire right off one way or the other. If it doesn't run, just don't try further as it is and change the wires out. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok will try that ..You have been very helpful and will update you on the results.